# Page not found (404) No MenuCategories matches the given query

Tags: python, django

Я создала приложение на джанго, суть такая:

Через админку добавляются данные, которые потом выводятся на главную страницу.

Данные я добавила, но на странице они не отображаются, выдает ошибку

```
Page not found (404) No MenuCategories matches the given query.
```

Как это можно исправить?

Вот мой код в `models.py`:

```
    from django.db import models


class MenuCategories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    explicit_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def children(self):
        return self.menucategories_set.all()

    def get_elder_ids(self):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.get_elder_ids() + [self.parent.id]
        else:
            return []
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^', include('new_menu.urls')),
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

new_menu/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.index, name='index'),
    path(r'(\d+)', views.index, name='index')
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'new_menu/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Скинь url. Тут, скорее всего, в нем дело

Comment: @hg добавила urls и views

Answer (score 0):

Ты вроде не добавила в context в файле view модель MenuCategories.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import MenuCategories
```

## Create your views here.

```
def index(request):
    menu = MenuCategories.objects.all()

    context = {'menu': menu}    
    return render(request, 'new_menu/index.html', context)
```

Далее в шаблоне new_menu выведи эти данные

```
    {% for i in menu %}
        {{ i }}
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: да и зачем тебе использовать в url регулярные выражения? Можно без них обойтись